# LazyList.decorate - InstantiateFactory: The constructor must exist and be public exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have that code:

```
public class User   
...
private List<Country> countries = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Country.class));
    private String country;

...
public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
...
```

In country class:

```
public class Country {

    private int countryId;
    private String countryName;

    public Country(int countryId, String countryName)
    {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public int getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(int countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

}
```

When I create a new User object I give this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InstantiateFactory: The constructor must exist and be public

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the only constructor you have is:

```
public Country(int countryId, String countryName)
```

while the factory expects to find *no-arg* constructor (common requirement):

```
public Country()
```

Add it to your `Country` class and you'll be fine.